# iOS Facebook SDK connect fails on iDevice

Tags: facebook, ios5, sdk

I'm using facebook connect in an iOS app (ARC, running on iOS 5). it was working fine on both simulator and device but since this morning it has stopped working on the device, it does still work on the simulator. On the device i get the fbDinNotLogin method called.

Now, I know the differece is simulator uses mobile facebook and my app uses native iOS facebook app, and I also know that you can tweak the facebook.m file to force the app to do the login elsewhere but I don't want to do that.

loading my previous builds from yesterday (where everything was working fine) also gives me the same results. so same code that ran yesterday doesn't run today. any idea why this happens? below is my delegate .m file:

**[EIDT]** I get various different behaiviours from the native facebook app. sometimes it opens facebook app, and stays there not coming back to my app. also sometimes it just goes back to my app quickly without allowing facebook app to ask me for my permission. I'm very confused. **[/EDIT]**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:       (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

user *userClass= [[user alloc] init];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) 
{
    // app already launched for the first time


}
else
{
    // This is the first launch ever
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [userClass CopyDbToDocumentsFolder];




}




facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"XXXXXXXXXX" andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
&& [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
[facebook authorize:nil];

}





return YES;
}

-(void)fbDidLogout
{
NSLog(@"Facebook loggedOut");
}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{


NSLog(@"Facebook Connect Failed");


}


- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];

}

- (void)fbSessionInvalidated
{
NSLog(@"Facebook Session Invalidated");
}



- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString*)accessToken
           expiresAt:(NSDate*)expiresAt
{
NSLog(@"Facebook Toekn was extended");
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:            (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Although the SDK attempts to refresh its access tokens when it makes API calls,
// it's a good practice to refresh the access token also when the app becomes active.
// This gives apps that seldom make api calls a higher chance of having a non expired
// access token.
[[self facebook] extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was indeed with facebook and not my app! my developer account had been failing to save changes etc, but it's back to a working now.